# Printer "Filter Failed" on HP laserjet

Tags: drivers, printing, hp, scanner

Have an HP Lasterjet MFP 227 printer connected through ethernet.  Has worked previously on this installation of Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS, suddenly it will not print because "filter failed"when printing.  It appears as a scanner but fails when I try to scan.

Installed HPLIP from the HP website version 3.23.8, deleting previous HPLIP

Attempted to install this printer through localhost/631.  It is apparently installed successfully.

Try a test print from localhost, it says "Filter Failed"

Reinstalled Ghostscript 9.50 sudo apt install --reinstall ghostscript. Same result. Rebooted after installation of HPLIP and rebooted printer.  Same result.

Several of these things I have done several times, deleting the printers that did not work, however I am stuck.

Looking around at some other threads got me this far.  One thread suggested to look into /var/log/cups/error_log, which helpfully informed me the printer had stopped because "filter failed".  I am not skilled enough to get any more out of reading this log.

Any suggestions?  I've read (but not understood) several threads on this subject, however I did not come away with any understanding of what more to try.

[EDIT] This [thread](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/cups-issue%3B-error-with-network-printer-usr-lib-cups-backend-hp-failed-on-client-4175601187/) suggested using lpstat -p then cupsenable [printername].  Same result "Filter Failed"